# Aestan Tray Menu crashes and needs to close

Tags: windows, wamp

I installed WAMP Server. When I click on start WampServer a Pop up window came up, said:

> Aestan Tray Menu has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. if you were in the middle of something, the information you were working on might be lost.

I have read that the reason can be Skype as it could use the same port, but I uncheck *use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections* but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by installing .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Found out by reading [Aestan Tray Menu has encountered a problem](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,78924) at WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ **2008** SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) or also maybe **.Net Framework**.

This should fix.